# Intellij Idea always fails postgresql connection

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

I cannot connect to postgresql from intellij idea while running app. It failes to connect to all kinds of datababes - to local db, remote dbs and so on. But it can easily connect these dbs using dbeaver and the app works perfectly on server. Also, the connection is okay if I use another machine for this. Do anyone know, how to fix it? Here is the stacktrace from intellij:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Auth failed
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:266) ~[liquibase-core-4.8.0.jar:na]
```

I tried everything but nothing helped

Comment: I connect to both oracle and postgresql constantly using IDEA's Database tool. Are you able to click "Test Connection" and get a "Succeeded" message when you look at your database connection properties?

Comment: yes, it is connecting well from IDEA's database tool, it fails only while application is running

Comment: Is that the entirety of the error message? I would think there is another section with better details.  Look in the db servers log file to see what it reports.

Comment: @cookerfresh , `ERROR: Auth failed`, check connection user name and password.

Comment: When I change my `HikariDataSource` config username and/or pass, I don't get that `Auth failed` error. I get errors indicating a bad username or pass. I wonder what triggers that `Auth failed` message in particular.